Cannot delete home folder of deleted user
I've mistakenly deleted a user with userdel without the -r option and now I can't delete its home folder. I'm logging in as root and I have su rights but when trying chmod or sudo rm -rfv /path/to/directory_to_delete I get "permission denied". I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS inside a container in Proxmox.
I pretty much tried everything that I could find and no solution worked for me. Any advices?
Output of whoami, groups and stat /home:
root@plex:~# whoami
root
root@plex:~# groups
root
root@plex:/# stat /home
File: /home
Size: 4096 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 directory
Device: fc07h/64519d Inode: 527236 Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root)
Access: 2024-04-09 20:11:52.770861904 +0000
Modify: 2023-02-11 11:20:26.990740365 +0000
Change: 2023-02-25 18:03:44.549062613 +0000
Birth: 2023-02-25 18:03:44.549062613 +0000

Output of rm -rf /home/birarid
rm: cannot remove '/home/birarid': Permission denied

Output of stat /home/birarid
 File: /home/birarid
 Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096        directory
 Device: fc07h/64519d    Inode: 527237      Links: 2
 Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (65534/  nobody)   Gid: (65534/ nogroup)
 Access: 2023-02-25 18:03:44.549062613 +0000
 Modify: 2023-02-11 11:20:26.053923205 +0000
 Change: 2023-02-25 18:03:44.549062613 +0000
 Birth: 2023-02-25 18:03:44.549062613 +0000


@kos Updated the question with that as well. Thank you for the guidance!

Is this inside a container? https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/i-cant-delete-a-nobody-nogroup-directory-from-a-container.106444/

@kos yeah it's running inside a container in Proxmox. Found a solution and updated the initial question with it. Thank you!

Solution:
I had some idmap in the container config (I'm running it inside Proxmox). After removing the configuration for that user I successfully deleted the home folder.

Will do in 2 days :)
